# Why one of my state is not triggered during my test

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-test

I followed Reso code youtube to create a small weather app, but I used the latest bloc library and flutter_bloc 4.0 also.

Base App: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTExlt1nJZI&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4jCBkrirvVGr5b8rC95VAQ5&index=7

BLoc Test: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6jFBiiP0Mc&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4jCBkrirvVGr5b8rC95VAQ5&index=8

The first 2 tests are working. For example, the below one does not give me any error:

```
test(
    'NEWER WAY BUT lONG-WINDED emits [WeatherLoading, WeatherLoaded] when successful',
    () {
  when(mockWeatherRepository.fetchWeather(any))
      .thenAnswer((_) async => weather);

  final bloc = WeatherBloc(mockWeatherRepository);

  bloc.add(GetWeather('London'));

  emitsExactly(bloc, [
    WeatherInitial(),
    WeatherLoading(),
    WeatherLoaded(weather),
  ]);
});
```

For some reason, that test below does not trigger the WeatherInitial.

```
blocTest(
  'emits [WeatherLoading, WeatherLoaded] when successful',
  build: () async {
    when(mockWeatherRepository.fetchWeather(any))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => weather);

    return WeatherBloc(mockWeatherRepository);
  },
  act: (bloc) => bloc.add(GetWeather('London')),
  expect: [
    WeatherInitial(),
    WeatherLoading(),
    WeatherLoaded(weather),
  ],
);
```

The error is:

```
ERROR: Expected: [
        WeatherInitial:WeatherInitial,
        WeatherLoading:WeatherLoading,
        WeatherLoaded:WeatherLoaded
      ]
Actual: [WeatherLoading:WeatherLoading, WeatherLoaded:WeatherLoaded]
Which: was WeatherLoading:<WeatherLoading> instead of WeatherInitial:<WeatherInitial> at location [0]
```

Do you have any clue why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is correct according to the official [bloc_test library](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_test):

```
skip is an optional int which can be used to skip any number of states.
The default value is 1 which skips the initialState of the bloc. 
skip can be overridden to include the initialState by setting skip to 0.
```

So if you want to include your "InitialState" just ,set the "skip" value to 0 :

```
.
.
.
skip: 0,
expect: [
    WeatherInitial(),
    WeatherLoading(),
    WeatherLoaded(weather),
  ],
```